# Vue3 Watchers - When are watchers being run in the order of lifecycle events?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am learning Vue 3, and I have come across a scenario where I am watching the $route. I am changing the $route from within the component using route params. To put it simply, I have a component which shows different data based on route params, and I am changing the route param from within the same component as well.

The thing is, this particular watcher is being called even when I am navigating away from that particular component. I tried putting lifecycle methods updated and beforeUnmount for the component. It seems that updated is called whenever the route changes, *while the component is mounted, and the route has changed.*
However, the watcher is triggered right when I completely navigate away from this particular route, and thereby unmount this component. *In that case, updated hook is not fired, but beforeUnmount and watcher are triggered.* Can someone point me to docs or explain what is the lifecycle order including watchers?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use vuex, if you don't, where is data stored? Do you change just data?

Comment: I dont use Vuex. Just have the data property, and I have setup a watcher for the route.

Comment: I would really like to see some code here to understand better and offer a solution, but for now, I suggest you use computed property and return the data you want to use based on the route.